# How can I format C# string output to contain newlines?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
strEmail = 
    "Hi All," 
    + "<br>"
    + "The User " 
    + lstDataSender[0].ReturnDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString()
    + " has been created on " 
    + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() 
    + "."
```

I am writing C# code to generate an email whenever a new user has been created.  I need the body of the mail in a mail format like

```
hi,

  The user "xxx" has been created on "todaysdate".


Thanks,
yyyy
```

so I need to insert linebreaks and bold for some characters. How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a plain text email (which it looks like it is), use `\r\n` for new lines.

```
strEmail = string.Concat("Hi All,\r\n\r\nThe User",
             lstDataSender[0].ReturnDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString(),
             "has been created on ",
             DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
             ".\r\n\r\nThanks, yyyy");
```

Strickly speaking this should be [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) to support different platforms, but I doubt this is a concern.

Comment: It contains `<br>`, so I'd assume it's html

Comment: I was assuming `<br>` was just an attempt to add the line break. There's no reason it needs to be html.

Comment: @ TheCodeKing i couldn't able to check it wether its in the required format, since there s issue in my admin team regarding mail sending. so can u help me to check this with a note pad

Comment: Typing the expected output into notepad won't help. Put a break point in your code and use the Text Visualizer in debugger to see the output message as plain text (hover over variable and select from down arrow).

Comment: I just noticed you also need bold? If so set `IsBodyHtml` and use html format instead. Bold isn't possible with plain text.

Comment: i have tried like this before itself but of no use, its displays as it is in a st.line

Comment: Where does it display as a single line? In debugger you have to view in the Text Visualizer otherwise it will just appear on one line.

Comment: @ The CodeKing:   hi, i had a textbox for date input,in which i select a date by using ajax tool comtrol in the format  12/23/2011. now i need a regular expression validator to validate the textbox so as characters should not be allowed to type in the text box meant for date..

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
yourMessage.IsBodyHtml = true
```

[Msdn-Reference can be found here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In order to form, you can use like below:

```
Response.Write("Hi,<br/><br/>The user.......");
```